# React js along with PHP (Yii2 framwork )

Tags: php, html, css, reactjs, yii2

I am a newbie to react js. I already have a project running on yii2 framework with frontend in traditional way ( Html , css ) but now need to run the frontend code using js.

I tried to include react files in AppAsset class like following

```
public $js = ["https://unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.min.js","https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.1.0/dist/react-dom.min.js","https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js","https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"];
```

and placing simple code in index.php

```
<div class="site-index">
  <div id="helloWorld"> </div>
</div>

<script type="text/babel">

class HelloWorld extends React.Component{
    render() {
      return(
        <div className='jumbotron text-center'>
          <h1> Welcome </h1>
          <p> Welcome to My Yii project powered by React Js </p>
        </div>
      ) ;
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld></HelloWorld>,document.getElementByid('helloWorld'));
  </script>
```

with no success. It just simply create a div site-index without actually rendering the render function of helloworld class.

I also tried to include all the react js to my index file but still the outcome is same. I guess  i am missing something on how to include the js files and that's why my render is not working.

Comment: Try this: `<HelloWorld/>` inside render method

Comment: Tried. But no success!

Comment: What happens if you add the js libraries at the top of `index.php`?

Comment: Also, update your question with your full AppAsset.php and Index.php so we can see if there are any issues.